# Media module file browser/selector widget

Tags: media

Is the interface shown in the image below specific to Media 7.x-2.x? I installed Media 7.x-1.x and I don't have the "View Library" tab shown here, I just have "Upload" and "Library".

[image: Media file selector widget (?)]